# python scrapy get_attribute is not defined

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

i want to get the `href` of the `<a>` tag.

I tried this;

```
def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.xpath('.//div[@class="aaaaaaaaaa"]/h3/span/a')
        for site in sites:
            Link = site.get_attribute('href')
            print Link
```

but I got that:

help please
     exceptions.AttributeError: 'Selector' object has no attribute 'get_attribute

Comment: You might try using something like `link = site.xpath('a/@href').extract()` instead of the `get_attribute()` line _(and maybe taking out the `/a` part in the earlier selection line,)_ if you haven't already :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    sites = sel.xpath('.//div[@class="block item-title"]/h3/span/a')
    for site in sites:
        Link = site.xpath('@href').extract()[0]
        print Link
```

Comment: as always, you the best